# creating a dynamic sqlite query in Native code

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an android app in which I am using some Native c++ code. Within the native code, I am querying the sqlite database and sending the result over to the calling function in Java. The problem is that my sqlite queries have to be dynamic depending on the value of an int variable in the native code. So basically, the query is not plain string but has to combined with the int variable before sending it to sqlite.

I need help in constructing the query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. The variable "LongInt" is the signed long long variable that holds the 10-12 digit integer.

```
char afterTime[100] = "SELECT _id FROM Picture where Time>%lld";
char afterTemp[100];
sprintf(afterTemp, "%lld", LongInt);
strcat(afterTime, afterTemp);
```

And it works fine! I am looking for alternative solutions at the same time.

Thanks,
Ab

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if the `int` is literally an `int`, or used as an index, but surely one of the following would work:

```
char *baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field=%d";
char *finalQuery = asprintf(baseQuery, magicInt);
```

Or alternatively,

```
char *magicStrings[4] = { "fish", "apple", "penguin", "rutabaga" };
char *baseQuery = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field='%s'";
char *finalQuery = asprintf(baseQuery, magicStrings[magicInt]);
```

And then execute query held in `finalQuery`

Comment: Ok. That sounds like what I am looking for. Will run through it and write back the result. Thanks!

Comment: and in case if the integer is a signed long long, it would be %lld, correct?